# How to pick the current color of a bitmap for vectorizing / tracing

Tags: inkscape

I have a .tif file and want to optimize it for the web.

I think I would cut out the pictures using GIMP and include them.

Now I am facing the problem how to pic the exact same color of some square/rectangle I want to re-make in Inkscape.

Answer (score 1):

The GIMP has a tool (named color picker) for selecting the color of any of the pixels on the image.

Once you pick up the color with the tool you can know what color is by clicking on the foreground color selector.